# joining 3 tables in sql server 2012 gives me duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have three tables joined with the left outer join and I need to check two columns in both tables but in the right table, I got the more than one record from the same column so I want only the value exists to record, not value '0' record.

I have 3 tables

[image: This is table 1]
[image: this is my second table]
[image: this is my third table]

for that, I have made this query result is almost there but it returns duplicate rows.
this is my SQL query

```
SELECT PWA.DT,
       P.MOULDCODE AS DieNo, 
       T.AssemblyWt AS AWT,
       T.WaxWt AS WWt,
       T.CoreWt AS CWT
FROM PRCWaxAss PWA
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PRC P ON PWA.PRCNO = P.PRCNO
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TDCWaxView T ON (P.MOULDCODE = T.DieNo)
                                 AND (P.METALCODE = T.MetalCode
                                   OR T.MetalCode = '0');
```

and this is my output
[image: Ourput]

"TDC" table and "PRC" table joined with left outer I have compared "die no" and "metal code" in both table if both are matched in PRC table then it will okay but if not matched "metal code" then I need to show record "metal code" value as "0" in TDC. in output image red highlighted row I don't want.
Can anyone help me..thank you in advance.

Comment: I dont see a duplicate in your output

Comment: I've done it for you, but I highly recommend you don't write your SQL on one line; it makes it impossible to read. *Good* use of line breaks and whitespace make any language (not just SQL) far easier for others and yourself to read. In regards to your data, please don't provide them as images; those you're asking for help from can't use them without transcribing them. Please take the time to post your data as tabular formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: where is the duplicate?

Comment: @Cetin Basoz .. I edited my question in output red highlighted row I don't  want

Comment: This is giving you the line you don't want. `(P.METALCODE = T.MetalCode                                   OR T.MetalCode = '0')`, Change to `T.METALCODE = CASE WHEN P.MetalCode = T.MetalCode THEN P.MetalCode ELSE '0' END`

Comment: T.METALCODE = CASE WHEN P.MetalCode = T.MetalCode THEN P.MetalCode ELSE '0' END ----- i replace this with P.METALCODE = CASE WHEN P.MetalCode = T.MetalCode THEN P.MetalCode ELSE '0' END....and it will give my out put .....thank you for helping.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  you can add this to answer so that I give you up vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OR` condition is giving you the multiple line output of what you don't want.

Give this a try and it should give you what you are looking for.

Replace this line `(P.METALCODE = T.MetalCode OR T.MetalCode = '0')`

With this `T.METALCODE = CASE WHEN P.MetalCode = T.MetalCode THEN P.MetalCode ELSE '0' END`